# Switches shut down when connecting my PC on a PoE port: help me find the failing part

Tags: troubleshooting, computer-building

A few months ago, we built a PC and ran into the following issue: when we plugged it into a PoE port on switch, the switch shut off. When using non-PoE ports, ethernet still didn’t seem to function, although we didn't spend much time ensuring the system or drivers were up to date given the PoE issue.

As the issue kept happening when the PSU was off (probably plugged in, though), we thought it was motherboard-related so we sent it back. Turns out we still have the issue with the new motherboard.

The issue doesn’t happen when:

- the PSU is not plugged into a power plug;
- the motherboard is not connected to anything but the CPU.

Right now, we’re trying to pinpoint the origin of the problem. The motherboard is installed in the case with only the CPU and its radiator installed. The PSU is switched off *and* unplugged. The board is connected to a running switch on a PoE port. Only our PC is connected to the switch.

We connect the motherboard to a single connector. We then plug in the PSU (still off) to main power. Does the switch remain on?

The switch turns off when any one of the following connector is plugged in:

- the 24-pin ATX connector,
- the 8-pin CPU power connector,
- the case 9-pin dual USB 2.0 connector (into either of the connector on the board).

The switch remains on when all of the following connectors are plugged in:
- the case 4-pin USB connector (I *believe* its the card reader)
- the case dual USB 3.0 connector.

What could be the source of the issue? How can I test it further?

---

The parts:

- Asus Z170 Pro Gaming motherboard
- Intel i7-6700K LGA1151 processor
- Cooler Master Silencio 652S case
- Corsair CX750M supply.

The issue is probably not switch related as we tried with two switches, both Cisco SG200-08P.

Comment: Did you try with an Ethernet cable that is known to be absolutely perfect?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz We tried with various cables, shielded or not, and tested them with a dumb, contact tester beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

This is a large issue with Asus mobos. So far the only solution seems to be power-related (cutting the ground or using a floating power supply). A simpler solution seems to be to ditch a PoE switch for a vanilla one, or use a non-Asus mobo.

Source: http://forum.tp-link.com/showthread.php?85051-Switch-shuts-down-when-connected-to-modern-Asus-motherboards/page2&s=5bf504967f4dff846e94aabb81daec45

Comment: If you can't simply remove the PoE switch from your environment, just put a small non PoE switch between your computer and the PoE switch. If you're feeling lucky, you could also try disabling PoE on the specific port used by your PC.